# Gridview in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-mvc-4, syncfusion

I am working on MVC4 Gridview.

I saw the video [MVC4 Gridview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5HwUTYMbjM)

In this video narrator said to add 4 dll files namely

1. Syncfusion.Core.dll
2. Syncfusion.Grid.Mvc.dll
3. Syncfusion.Linq.Base.dll
4. Syncfusion.Shared.Mvc.dll

In this list I downloaded **file 1(Syncfusion.Core.dll)** but unable to find any help for other 3 files so what can I do to download them or Please tell any substitute of them.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: this grid should be part of a third party component package, did you download the installer from here: http://www.syncfusion.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to this link, http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/aspnet-mvc/grid, you should find the demos and package to download.